# Rails: How to display category of products

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my app i need to find category of the product. But don't know how to find it. Category has many sub-categories. Subcategory has many products. SubCategory and product are related through product_sub_category. Is there any way to know the category of product? Help!

```
Category model is:
  has_many :sub_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_categories, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :products, :through => :sub_categories

Sub-category model:
  attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :sub_category, :sub_category_url
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :product_sub_categories
  has_many :products, :through => :product_sub_categories
  has_one :photo, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, :allow_destroy => true

ProductSubCategory
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :sub_category
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :sub_category_id
  before_save :assign_category_id

Product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :product_sub_categories
  has_many   :sub_categories, :through => :product_sub_categories
  has_many   :categories, :through => :sub_categories 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_sub_categories
```

I am showing Product page and want to display its category. How to do this? Let me know if i need to provide any other info.

Comment: "product has many categories" - which one of those you want to display?

Comment: according to your code, a product has many subcategories and categories.  is this correct and intentional?

Comment: @aguynamedloren yes, product can have many sub-cat and cats

Comment: @SergioTulentsev all related categories. Actually i need to match the cake-category with category of product. If product belogs to category, display something else nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you just need to get the categories the product belongs to, not the sub categories while showing the product information(show action).

in your controller

```
def show
  @product = Product.includes(:categories).find(params[:id])
end
```

and in your view(show.html.erb)

```
<% @product.categories.each do |category| %>
  <span><%= category.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will help. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: it gives something like this  #<Category:0xa4cf9c8>

Comment: It must be category.name or whatever field you are using to display the name. :)
Please mark it accepted if it does what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
@products = Product.all
```

In your views

```
@products.each do |product|    
  product_category = product.sub_category.category
end
```

By doing this you get the product's category objects

Comment: but i need to find category of given product. In controller i have @product = Product.find(params[:id])

Comment: @product.sub_category.category.name

Answer (score 0):

**product.category** will give you the ID of the Product's category. And **product.categroy.name** will give you the NAME of the Product's category. You can use it in your view.

Note: If you have has_many and belongs_to relation between them. Thanks 
Enjoy!